# How to get all the files older than N minutes?

Tags: c#, file

I have to get all the files older than 2 minutes from a directory.

```
string sDir ="C:\\Test";
string[] files;
files = Directory.GetFiles(sDir, @"*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

I can loop through the files array and get the File attribute to get the File Creation Time.

```
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(files);
```

But I would like to do the filtering at the `GetFiles` level.

Comment: "I would like to get the filtering at GetFiles level" - You're saying you want `GetFiles()` to perform that filtering for you?  There is simply no support for that.  See also [`Directory.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles) and [`DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles).

Comment: I don't think thats possible, use linq like suggested in the answers

Comment: Yeah, life is like that some times. You can set `EnumerationOptions` or a `SearchOption` but neither allows the filtering you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try *Linq* to query these files:

```
  using System.IO; 
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  DateTime limit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2);

  var files = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(sDir, @"*.xml", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
    .Where(file => new FileInfo(file).CreationTime < limit)
    .ToArray(); // if you want an array of the files
```